# cannot find module "react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook" error when updating to React 16.2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, react-dom

Changed react and react-dom to 16.2.0 in my package JSON and receiving the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook"
```

Have tried clearing my node_modules, reinstalling everything, starting with a fresh project and adding dependencies in small chunks to narrow down the issue, and trying just about every option already seen on stack overflow.

my package.json is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "..."
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
        "build": "webpack -p"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "connect-mongo": "^2.0.0",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "express-session": "^1.15.6",
        "moment": "^2.19.3",
        "mongoose": "^4.13.6",
        "multer": "^1.3.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
        "passport": "^0.4.0",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "qs": "^6.5.1",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-click-outside": "^3.0.0",
        "react-dom": "16.2.0",
        "react-redux": "5.0.6",
        "redux": "3.7.2",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-promise-middleware": "^5.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "underscore": "^1.8.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "serve": "^6.4.1",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
        "svg-sprite-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
        "svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.3",
        "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
        "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "homepage": ""
}
```

After placing a breakpoint at the line erroring out, it seems that the stack trace is coming form the import of react-dom, but if that is at the latest version matching react, i don't understand why i am having this issue.

Out of options that I can think of, would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Try upgrade webpack

Answer (score 1):

> Have tried clearing my node_modules, reinstalling everything

Remember that since NPM 5-th version it generates package lock file, without purging that reinstalling modules will not work appropriately.

Also check following - if some package has own dependency on old `react` package version, it will be installed into nested `node_modules` directory, and then everything is dependent on project/loaders structure. In come circumstance, invalid new or old package version will be loaded. In some npm packages, like `graphql`, special warning added for that case: "Maybe you have installed different version of package".

So, check other packages' versions, and maybe update them.